# Can a compiler automatically move a function argument if the function call is the return statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the following situation can a compiler automatically move the function argument *v* or does it have to be declared manually?

```cpp
std::vector Filter(std::vector v);

void DoSomeStuffAndCallFilter(std::vector v)
{
  // do some stuff to v

  // can the compiler automatically std::move v in this call?
  // ie. return Filter(std::move(v));
  //
  return Filter(v);
}
```

Comment: `Filter` takes an `vector` as copy so no, to activate move semantics you need to take it per rvalue reference and use `std::move`

Comment: It takes `vector` as a copy to save writing two overloads `const std::vector &` and `std::vector &&`. If it took an r-value would you still need to manually write `std::move` in the calling code?

Comment: @Valerij: That's false. He does need to call `std::move` when he passes `v` to `Filter`, but the signature of `Filter` does not need to change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, the compiler can do so as an allowed optimisation under the as-if rule, because it knows the destructor and copy-constructor of your `std::vector` intimately, and can thus prove there is no difference to the observable behavior.

Still, it is a "quality of implementation issue", and depends on heavy optimisations being done.

Comment: Would you recommend adding the `std::move` in that situation or just leave it up to the compiler to potentially optimise?

Comment: @fun4jimmy: I'd recommend to add `std::move`. It makes the programmers intent clear and will work reliably across all compilers.